# Need help fixing orientation for certain UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a video application with a number of screens, I would like all those screens to allow portrait only **except** for the video player screen that can manually go from from portrait to landscape.

Now I have the following in the video player screen

```
#pragma mark - CHANGE ORIENTATION METHODS


- (void)changeOrientation {

NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

}
```

And then in the listings screen I have the following to try and fix the orientation to portrait only.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Now when I load the app it seems to set the orientation to portrait, the problem is on the video player screen I have a back button. If that screen is in landscape mode and I click back the

> shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

doesn't get called and it is stuck in landscape mode.

How can I force it call the above, or is there are a better way to approach this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force a change in the orientation programmatically:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Of course you need to enable the landscape orientations in your project target->Deployment Info->Device Orientation. I hope it helps.